# .htaccess to redirect http to https for sensitive areas

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl

I am just finally updating my site from Joomla 1.5 and Virtuemart 1.1.9 to Joomla 2.5 and Virtuemart 2. I have tried enabling the SSL for sensitive areas in Virtuemart but it is not working and I would like to use .htaccess to do the redirect instead.

I have tried this code and it would work if my site was located in the root of the website but it is in a subfolder i.e. www.uniqbuy.com/electronics

How can I get this code to not strip electronics from the URL when redirecting to https?

```
# Force SSL on checkout login account and admin pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} checkout|login|my-account|administrator|webshop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# Remove SSL on other pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !checkout|login|my-account|administrator|webshop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%2/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# Force www for non https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your second rule appears to be using wrong regex. Try this code:

```
# Force SSL on checkout login account and admin pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (checkout|login|my-account|administrator|webshop)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove SSL on other pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(checkout|login|my-account|administrator|webshop)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%2/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force www for non https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had managed to get it working with my installation on a subfolder but it was not keeping the cart contents in memory switching between http and https. Then found the Yireo SSL Redirection which is great and solved all the problems.